# Default column sorting from datagrid

Tags: asp.net

I have 5 bound columns to be retrieved from the database but I want that on page load event the retrieval of data should be sorted according to that column only,

What I need to do..plz help me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend having the data sorted for you by the database. I presume you have a database query somewhere - either in the ASP.NET page, in a stored procedure, or in your object model - what you need to do is specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

For example, if you have the following SQL statement used to populate your DataGrid:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
FROM MyTable
```

And you want the results sorted by, say, `Col3`, use the following query instead:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Col3
```

Happy Programming!